# Difference between COM DLL and ActiveX control

Tags: dll, com, activex

Few similarities I know..

- Both cannot execute by themself. It needs some program to instantiate it.
- COM DLL & ActiveX controls are platform independant. (is it so...?)
- Both requires to support the interface `IUnknown` and exposes three methods `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, and `Release`.
- It also requires to be registered before using and un-registered after done with it.

But how are they different? Can someone please list it down?

Also my understanding is ActiveX controls are OLE custom controls (OCX). I have heard of terms like ActiveX DLLs. Is it another form of ActiveX control or something different?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ActiveX is a flavor of COM.  COM+, OLE, and DCOM are also flavors of COM.  COM just means Component Object Model.  An ActiveX object is just an OLE object that supports `IUnknown`.

COM is a *system-level* standard and provides model services to facilitate the construction of higher-level functionality.  OLE and ActiveX are high-level services built on top of the COM foundation.  COM, ActiveX, and OLE are very similar in nature but ActiveX and OLE provide more application-level features.