# ActiveX and COM

Tags: c++, gcc, com, activex

I'm starting with C++ and a few questions came up:

1. What is the difference between ActiveX and COM?
2. Can I use them with a GCC compiler (like MinGW)?

I hope you can help me.

Kind regards and thanks for advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763276/difference-between-com-dll-activex-control

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is built using COM. In a way, it is a further feature development of it.

You can use MinGW, though it is not a simple task, as you will have to code a lot (type info, virtual tables, etc).